# OutputDataReceived does not work with windows git.exe

Tags: c#, .net, console

I do have a strange problem: I try to call git.exe to clone a repository via a small c# console-application->

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "path/to/git/git.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "clone SomeGitRepoWhichRequiresPassword";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
p.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;
p.Exited += Exited;

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

When I try to clone a Repository which needs user-input (e.g. entering a ssh-password) none of the events is triggered so I cannot react to that input programmaticly. Is there a way to really get ALL command-output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to enter password programatically? You can try to write password in Git repository URL like this:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about cloning a repo over ssh? Some repos are reachable via ssh only ...

Comment: I think better approach for working with git repositories programmatically is libgit2 (http://libgit2.github.com/)